# Upgrading from MathJax 2.7.5 to 3.0, trying to preserve a custom TeX environment

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, mathjax, tex

I use MathJax with my Jekyll blog on GitHub Pages. In fact, I wrote a blog post on exactly what steps I took to set up MathJax 2.7.5: ["MathJax in Jekyll"](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/08/05/mathjax-in-jekyll/) (August 2018)

For a couple of posts, I wanted to use a `psmallmatrix` environment, like the one from the `mathtools` package: `$$\begin{psmallmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{psmallmatrix}$$`. I know how I would create such an environment in actual TeX, using the `\newenvironment` command: ["How do I make a small pmatrix?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156018/126270)

But to get the command "pre-loaded" in MathJax 2.7.5, I was doing this, cargo-culting some code from MathJax's version of the AMSmath package:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: [
      "MathMenu.js",
      "MathZoom.js",
      "AssistiveMML.js",
      "a11y/accessibility-menu.js"
    ],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/CommonHTML"],
    TeX: {
      extensions: [
        "AMSmath.js",
        "AMSsymbols.js",
        "noErrors.js",
        "noUndefined.js",
      ]
    }
  });
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
    var TEX = MathJax.InputJax.TeX;
    var COLS = function (W) {
      var WW = [];
      for (var i = 0, m = W.length; i < m; i++)
        {WW[i] = TEX.Parse.prototype.Em(W[i])}
      return WW.join(" ");
    };
    TEX.Definitions.Add({
      environment: {
        psmallmatrix: ['Array',null,'(',')','c',COLS([1/3]),".2em",'S',1],
      }
    });
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js">
</script>
```

Sometime in the past year or so, MathJax 2.7.5 completely stopped working on GitHub, so I'm trying to upgrade to MathJax 3.0.

I have managed to translate the non-tricky parts of this config by using [MathJax's own config converter](https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/convert-configuration/convert-configuration.html), but I don't know what to do about my hand-crafted `psmallmatrix`.
Here's what I have now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    packages: ['base', 'ams'],
  },
  loader: {
    load: ['ui/menu', '[tex]/ams'],
  },
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js">
</script>
```

How can I recover my hand-crafted `psmallmatrix` environment, in MathJax 3.0? The formatting need only be roughly equivalent, as long as I can keep invoking it with `\begin{psmallmatrix}`.

I should mention that [the MathJax docs on "Defining TeX Macros"](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros.html) give an example of how to "preload" the TeX parser with a macro, roughly equivalent to what `\newcommand` would do. The docs say:

```
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    macros: {
      RR: "{\\bf R}",
      bold: ["{\\bf #1}", 1]
    }
  }
};
```

But the docs are missing any examples of how to do the same kind of thing for `\newenvironment`.

Comment: I crossposted this question on [the MathJax Users forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/mathjax-users/lWj4CeN70oY) a week ago, but it seems pretty dead over there.

Comment: The un-minified source code for MathJax 3's `ams` extension is [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-src/blob/2b74fc1/ts/input/tex/ams/AmsConfiguration.ts) (and its sibling source files), but I can't figure out how MathJax finds one bit of code from another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a configuration that adds the `psmallmatrix` environment to the AMS environment list.  There should be a method to pre-configure environments that is similar to what is done for macros.  I've made a [feature request](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2505) for it in the MathJax GitHub repository.

For now, add

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    ready() {
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
      const Macro = MathJax._.input.tex.Symbol.Macro;
      const MapHandler = MathJax._.input.tex.MapHandler.MapHandler;
      const Array = MathJax._.input.tex.ams.AmsMethods.AmsMethods.Array;
      const env = new Macro('psmallmatrix', Array, [null,'(',')','c','.333em','.2em','S',1]);
      MapHandler.getMap('AMSmath-environment').add('psmallmatrix', env);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

as your configuration to enable the `psmallmatrix` environment.

Comment: When I [try this](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/blog/commit/579431b0a1f998843346c30bade56e1ce3b66113), I get a JS error that Safari console reports as `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: t.setAttribute is not a function. (In 't.setAttribute(e,r)', 't.setAttribute' is undefined)` and Chrome console reports as `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.setAttribute is not a function / at c.setAttribute (tex-chtml.js:1) at e.assistiveMml (tex-chtml.js:1) [...] at new Promise (<anonymous>)`. Thoughts?

Comment: Try disabling the assistive-mml extension (where Chrome says the error is occurring) by adding `options: {renderActions: {assistiveMml: []}}` to the configuration (at the top level), and see if that lets the page process.  Also, this may be related to the content of the page (it worked on the page you sent me).  Are there any escaped dollar signs on the page?

Comment: Also, if you remove the configuration, does the page process (other than the missing psmallmatrix environments)?

Comment: _it worked on the page you sent me_ — You mean [this page](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/08/05/mathjax-in-jekyll/) renders for you? For me, after [adding `ready()`](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/blog/commit/579431b0a1f99884), I see [this](https://i.imgur.com/wbJthXT.png). After [removing `ready()` again](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/blog/commit/51a80de73b0ec118820), I see [this](https://i.imgur.com/TQwdbMA.png). After [re-adding it and disabling `assistiveMml`](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/blog/commit/cb63c426b2a7bae), I see [this](https://i.imgur.com/vyNKzDo.png).

Comment: Sorry, you didn't sent a page (I've been answering too many questions today, and got you mixed up with another one).  The example matrix that fails for you does work for me, so I'm confused, and will have to copy your page and see what happens there.  Can you verify that you are getting version 3.0.5 in one of the links that shows some math (by using the MathJax contextual menu and selecting "About MathJax")?

Comment: Sorry. misunderstanding.  When I put your content into my own page, it works for me.  I have to investigate your page further.  Also when I copy the generated MathML from your page into mine, it displays.  Curious.

Comment: OK, it was my fault.  The `['.333em']` should be just `'.333em'` (with no brackets).  When I make this change in the data in your page and re-typeset, it renders properly.  Still not sure why my page renders with the array.  Weird.  I edited the code snippet in my answer.

Comment: That worked! After pushing [this squashed patch](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/blog/commit/420dbabb235ee9c), I now see [this](https://i.imgur.com/9S8mpUR.png). The parens look bigger and heavier than I remember, but that's almost certainly wishful thinking on my part. I think we've successfully regained the rendering behavior I used to have! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, me again. I just now noticed that the code has bit-rotted again. I haven't changed [the squashed patch](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/blog/commit/420dbabb235ee9c) or messed with anything in `_include` since Aug 2020, but, as of Feb 2021, I now see it rendering like [this](https://i.imgur.com/1124d7q.png) in Safari (and similarly in Chrome).

Comment: Change `default` to `AmsMethods` in the line that defines the `Array` variable.  Version 3.1.2 changed that structure.

Comment: That worked! Here's [the patch](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/blog/commit/6784fd9015e8219021da8f5f5c87f151433f251c), for anyone following along at home. Thanks!